# SUBLIS and splicing

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to find out if there is a easy way of doing a mixture of `SUBLIS` and backquote in Common Lisp without having to write my own.

A regular `SUBLIS` will give me the following result:

```
CL> (sublis '((X . (1 2 3))) '(bar (foo X)))
(BAR (FOO (1 2 3)))
```

(The general case can be an arbitrarily complex tree, not just a simple list.)

But I am looking into a version that splices the list into the substitution, like:

```
CL> (sublis1 '((X . (1 2 3))) '(bar (foo X)))
(BAR (FOO 1 2 3))
```

Like it happens on backquote and comma-atsign:

```
CL> (let ((x (list 1 2 3))) `(bar (foo ,@x)))
(BAR (FOO 1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware there is no standard function to do this.
If the splice variable is always the end of a list, you can use `:test #'equal` like so:

```
(sublis '(((x) . (1 2 3))) 
        '(bar (foo x))
        :test #'equal)

=> (BAR (FOO 1 2 3))
```

For anything else the structure changes are too difficult for `sublis`.
It's not too hard to write, though, as the answer that appeared while I was writing an implementation shows.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking of not reinventing the wheel, you could use the code-walker shipped with your Common Lisp implementation, if available. For example
In SBCL, a simple substitution where FOO is explicit can be done as follows:

```lisp
(sb-walker:walk-form '(bar (foo X))
                     nil
                     (lambda (form context env)
                       (declare (ignore context env))
                       (if (equal form '(foo x))
                           '(foo 1 2 3)
                         form)))
```

In your case, however, you want to match X, not FOO.  It is not much
harder, but let's use the pattern matching library
[OPTIMA](https://github.com/m2ym/optima) to illustrate how it works:

```lisp
(sb-walker:walk-form '(bar (foo X))
                     nil
                     (lambda (form context env)
                       (declare (ignore context env))
                       (optima:match form
                         ((list head 'x) (list head 1 2 3))
                         (_ form))))
```

Here there is no risk of going into an infinite walk, because `(foo 1 2 3)` 
cannot match the first rule. However, you might want to provide
a secondary value of T to prevent the walker to recurse into the
resulting form.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no standard CL function to do that; (substitute et al. only work on sequences, not on tree; subst et al. work on tree, but only substitute a fixed new).
2. The only way NOT to do it, would be to use a library that would do it, or more. I can think only of some pattern matching library.

Perhaps you could look up for some code implementing the same thing you have to implement and with some luck, locate and find the same function you want.

But honestly, finding a pattern matching library and learning how to use it to do what you want, or locating a similar program with that function already implemented looks to me MUCH MORE WORK, and MUCH LESS FUN WORK than programming it.   Even asking that on stackoverflow looks like more work than writing it!

```
(defun sublis1 (bindings tree)
  (cond
    ((null tree) tree)
    ((atom tree) ;; a dotted list in the tree.
     (cdr (assoc tree bindings)))
    ((let ((entry (assoc (car tree) bindings)))
       (when entry
         (append (cdr entry) (sublis1 bindings (cdr tree))))))
    ((atom (car tree))
     (cons (car tree)
           (sublis1 bindings (cdr tree))))
    (t
     (cons (sublis1 bindings (car tree))
           (sublis1 bindings (cdr tree))))))

(sublis1 '((X . (1 2 3))) '(bar (foo X)))
--> (bar (foo 1 2 3))
```

Comment: Every piece of code can have bugs if there exists a core function to do the job, it would be better use it instead of writing a new one. This is the real reason for the question. We all can think of ways to write the function sublis1.

Comment: Exactly, sorry for not being clear: the idea was not to ask for an implementation of `sublis1` (I imagined it would not be difficult), but to see if there's a simple solution out there, battle tested, etc.  Anyway, thanks for the implementation!